# How to create a bulletproof build script for a React App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, production-environment

I have a mildly complex React project - basically a bag of sexy UI components, that I would love to put out there for people to enjoy. The idea is that you modify the App.js, cut out the bs you're not using, hit `yarn build` or `npm run build` and end up with a build folder - self-contained, uglified, ready for the deploy.

I know about two leading solutions, a `react-scripts` one and a `webpack`-based one. Assuming I want to give my forking peers minimum of configuration and a working prod build they can instantly hook up and have running, which way is "the best" (the fastest, the simplest, the most dependency-free)?

I was given four days to do it. After two full of unclear signals, compilation errors and general dis-functionality of my build (regarding using both of the above mentioned methods) I am taking a step back, trying to wrap my head around it for the last time. I have, like, one fourteen questions about the matter, yet decided to go for a more general phrasing. Please be gentle.

Comment: This will be closed as too broad and/or opinion based. You should decide on one of the two and ask specific questions to keep it open.

Comment: Should I delete it? @DanielHilgarth

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I often have questions like this, and I am searching for a place where to put them. So far I went to Computer Science for those that are related to theory of computing, algorithms and such and Software Development for theoretical software question. But where should I got with this kind of specific structure questions where half stack or more is defined I too am not 100% sure. Judging by your score I am hoping you could advise ;)

Comment: [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is super easy what kind of error did you get ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu Well, when my `package.json` has `"build": "react-scripts build"`, and I go `yarn build` the `build` folder gets created - looks like a newborn that's smiling, no tears. Then, to test it, I take it outside, to the `Desktop`, run it with `VS Code` and "go live" with it. It reveals itself at port 5500, but nothing's there - no errors, neither. `html` file seems fine, yet the script is just not there.

Comment: ..I mean it *is* there, just does not get displayed! to be precise.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith: To be honest, I don't know. I have the same problem with these kinds of questions

Comment: @PacoPacici Start with the [getting-started](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started) app , understand how things gets rendered and after add your components.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [CRA](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) (create-react-app)